# find value in array cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp, find

Hey guys I am trying to get a value from an array in my events_controller.php file.
Event belongsTo Entity and Entity hasMany Event. I need this value to perform some other logic but im really stuck and i know it should be an easy thing to do.

I am trying to get the value of Entity.user_id from this array.

```
Array
(
[Event] => Array
    (
        [id] => 19
        [entity_id] => 8
        [name] => new event
        [time_start] => 2011-02-26 19:09:00
        [time_end] => 2011-02-26 19:09:00
        [dateStart] => 0000-00-00
        [dateEnd] => 0000-00-00
        [description] => jgiuguygo
        [ageRange] => 67
    )

[Entity] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [user_id] => 14
        [location_id] => 15
        [type] => EVENT
    )

[Eventfeedback] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

the above matrix i obtained with this code:

```
$value = $this->Event->read();
pr($value);
```

Now this is as close as I can get...

```
Array
(
[Entity] => Array
    (
        [user_id] => 14
    )

[Event] => Array
    (
        [id] => 19
    )

[Eventfeedback] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

with this code

```
$value = $this->Event->read('Entity.user_id');
pr($value);
```

An last try i got this array

```
Array
(
[Entity] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [user_id] => 11
        [location_id] => 8
        [type] => sdfsdfdsf
    )

[User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [firstName] => luis
        [lastName] => pooya
        [username] => admin
        [password] => 94c882c8506497a9f031ca5a4db6d0143c97fe45
        [role] => admin
        [email] => some
    )

[Location] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [name] => First Nation University of Canada
        [xCoordinate] => 0
        [yCoordinate] => 0
    )

[Establishment] => Array
    (
    )

[Event] => Array
    (
    )

[Vmachine] => Array
    (
    )
)
```

with this code

```
$value = $this->Event->Entity->find('user_id');
pr($value);
```

Hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.Luis

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understood you correctly. But to get user_id in your examples would be like

```
$value = $this->Event->read('Entity.user_id');
pr($value['Entity']['user_id']);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$event = $this->Event->read();
$userId = $event['Entity']['user_id'];
```